# setup.bash setup.sh setup.zsh

Tags: ros, bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to find out the differences between 3 files created when using the command 'rosws init ~/fuerte-ws /opt/ros/fuerte' : setup.bash setup.sh setup.zsh. In the rosbuild tutorial, it tells me to source setup.sh. But in catkin tutorial, we source setup.bash. So do these three files serve the same function? Why no one uses setup.zsh? What is it?

Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188737/setup.bash-setup.sh-setup.zsh/) by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2014-08-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They are for [different shells in linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Shell_categories)

bash is default shell in ubuntu. Depending on which shell you are using you can source respective setup.

you can check which shell you are using in by using `echo $SHELL`

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7